# Difference between 2 dates in to populate Textbox in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, userform

I have 2 textboxes which captures the date chosen from their respective datepickers. I'd like to get the difference in days between these dates. I keep getting the unable to get the networkdays property of the worksheetfunction class error when i run my form.

My code:

```
Dim Holidays As Range
Set Holidays = Worksheets("Holidays").Range("A:A")
If IsEmpty(TextBox1.Value) = True Then
TATtxt.Value = ""
ElseIf IsEmpty(TextBox1.Value) = False And TextBox2.Value <= TextBox1.Value 
Then
TATtxt.Value = _
WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(TextBox2.Value, TextBox1.Value, Holidays)
End If
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code write the following:

```
Dim Holidays As Range
Set Holidays = Worksheets("Holidays").Range("A:A")
If IsEmpty(TextBox1.Value) = True Then
TATtxt.Value = ""
ElseIf IsEmpty(TextBox1.Value) = False And TextBox2.Value <= TextBox1.Value 
Then
MsgBox TextBox2.Value & "-"& TextBox1.Value
TATtxt.Value = _
WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(TextBox2.Value, TextBox1.Value)
End If
```

It would show you the values of the dates in a msgbox. Then examine them, probably one of them is not correct.

And remove the `Holidays` part in the NetworkDays, as per the documentation it should be:
*Holidays - an optional range of one or more dates to exclude from the working calendar, such as state and federal holidays and floating holidays. The list can be either a range of cells that contains the dates or an array constant of the serial numbers that represent the dates.*

Documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-networkdays-method-excel

In general, do the following to see how the formula works. Open a new Excel. In a new module write the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrintNetworkDays()

    Dim dtStartDate     As Date
    Dim dtEndDate       As Date
    Dim rngHolidays     As Range

    dtStartDate = DateSerial(2017, 7, 1)
    dtEndDate = DateSerial(2017, 8, 1)

    Set rngHolidays = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

    rngHolidays(1, 1) = DateSerial(2017, 7, 5)
    rngHolidays(2, 1) = DateSerial(2017, 7, 6)
    rngHolidays(3, 1) = DateSerial(2017, 7, 7)
    rngHolidays(4, 1) = DateSerial(2017, 7, 8)
    rngHolidays(5, 1) = DateSerial(2017, 7, 9)

    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(dtStartDate, dtEndDate, rngHolidays)

End Sub
```

Run it. Then you would see the dates, which are holidays, excluded from your calculations.

Comment: thanks vityata...i added the msgbox code but the values i get are correct and i still get the error when i run the form...am i missing anything when i use the networkdays function?

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the values that you get in the msgbox, @agatha

Comment: thanks it works when i remove the holidays from the argument. but then how do i exclude the dates which falls on a holiday?

Comment: @agatha, Put them in a range and refer the range as a 3. argument.

Comment: thanks...i did have a declaration declaring the range as holidays (not sure if this is incorrect) Dim Holidays As Range
Set Holidays = Worksheets("Holidays").Range("A:A")? my apologies

Comment: @agatha - take a new look of my answer, I have updated it a bit.

Comment: @vityata...thanks for your help and suggestions I have found what's causing the error :) appreciate your inputs

Comment: it was the range for the holidays i was using :) thanks again!